# Firefox opens 5 processes as soon I start, is it normal?

Tags: firefox

My Firefox is using a lot of memory. I noticed that as soon I open the firefox browser (with default tab), it opens 5 processes in the taskbar. After that it starts one process for each tab. Is this normal behavior of Firefox or is it some problem with my browser?

[image: Here's the screenshot:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal and it's not a lot of memory.

Modern browsers use processes to implement the sandbox. Process isolation makes sure that exploiting something on one page doesn't let attacker access data of other ones.

Browser extensions and plugins can also be run in separate processes for the same reason.

500 MB is not a lot of used memory for a browser. Modern web uses up quite a lot of resources if you want the full experience without sacrificing on security.

Comment: Thanks but its the initial memory without loading any URL. with 3-4 tabs open it uses between 2-3GB memory.

Comment: I still wouldn't consider that abnormal

Comment: @Noor the 492MB is the *total* usage of all the sub-processes, not in addition to them.